# how do I get cucumber-js to compile typescript files

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm trying to refactor a Playwright test suite to use cucumber-js on top of it, but I keep getting

```
C:\devl\js\nationwide-ways-to-pay\tests\page\test-support.page.ts:1
import { Locator, Page } from '@playwright/test';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Command I'm running

```
node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js --require-module ts-node/register --require step-definitions/**/*.ts --format progress-bar --require tests/page/*.ts features/**/*.feature
```

I have also tried adding `"type": "module"` to my package.json, and changing my `module` to es2015 in my tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: did you try to set         `"module": "commonjs"`, in tscnofig?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Regarding your deleted/closed question, you may find there is value in undeleting it. While I appreciate it is annoying to bump into closure rules you didn't know about, you might get some more remarks in the comments that will assist you.